# jquery autocomplete- add data to list on select event

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I am using jquery autocomplete with a json datasource.

This is my code:
clientId, clientName are the id's of the input fields.

```
$("#clientId").autocomplete({
        source: function(request, response){
            var clientId=request.term;
            $.ajax({
                type:"GET",
                url:"getClients.htm?ClientId=" + clientId +"&ClientName=",
                dataType:"json",
                success: function(data){
                    if(pageCountClientId == 0){
                data.push({clientId:"More Options",clientName:"More Options"});
                        pageCountClientId++;
                    }
                    else{
                data.push({clientId:"Previous Options",clientName:"Previous Options"});
                        pageCountClientId++;
                    }
                    response($.map(data,function(value,key){
                        return{
                            label:value.clientId,
                            value:value.clientName
                        };
                    }));                                    
                }
            });
        },
        minLength: 1,
        select: function(event, ui){
            if(ui.item.value == "More Options"){
                pageCountClientId++;
            }
            else if(ui.item.value == "Previous Options"){
                pageCountClientId--;
            }
            else{
                $("#clientName").val(ui.item.value);
                $("#clientId").val(ui.item.label);
                $("#clientName").attr("disabled", "disabled"); 
                $("#clientId").attr("disabled", "disabled");
            }
            return false;
        },
    });
```

So now when the user clicks on the 'More Options' value, in the select event I want to get the next set of results and display it in the dropdown which appears. How to make it happen. any pointers in the right direction will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should be a matter of calling `search` from the `select` handler. As you may have discovered, however, this doesn't work [quite right](http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/8784).

You should be able to make it work by adding a small timeout:

```
select: function(event, ui){
    if(ui.item.value == "More Options"){
        pageCountClientId++;
        setTimeout($.proxy(function () {
            $(this).autocomplete('search', this.value);
        }, this), 1);
    }
    else if(ui.item.value == "Previous Options"){
        pageCountClientId--;
        setTimeout($.proxy(function () {
            $(this).autocomplete('search', this.value);
        }, this), 1);
    }
    else{
        $("#clientName").val(ui.item.value);
        $("#clientId").val(ui.item.label);
        $("#clientName").attr("disabled", "disabled"); 
        $("#clientId").attr("disabled", "disabled");
    }
    return false;
},
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/fTFkY/2/

The example uses a local source but simulates an AJAX request. Hopefully this helps!

Comment: Thank you Andrew!! it worked. I was able to make an ajax call with the proxy function and search function of Auto complete